# 24V output with microcontroller using mosfets

Tags: microcontroller, transistors

I want to controll 24V output which will be used by PLC with 3V3 logic uC.

I've created sth like this:
[image]

`Q1` is my output from uC. `VIN1` is supply voltage and `COM1` common of it. I want to have various output voltage (like 5-24). But let's focus only on 24V now.   Will this circuit work? What if there will be no load on `Q1OUT`? Will transistor boil to death? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance and best regards,
g.voooo16.

Comment: Load goes in series with V+ or Common for low or high side switch. No load=open circuit

Answer (score 1):

A MOSFET needs a gate voltage well above the source to conduct properly, for your type ~ 10V. Obviously your circuit can't deliver this. That's why the common way to use such a transistor is with the source grounded and the load at the drain, and teh collector of the PC817 at a suitable voltage level (12V would be OK).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZzkOS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There are far better and more efficient ways of doing this but this is probably the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Since the signal levels of **N** channel mosfets require a positive gate voltage as seen from source, you'll need to make 24V + Vgate.
Which requires a **high side gate driver**. (eg: a boost converter such as LT1161 )

Instead, you could use **P** channel mosfets. You turn them on by pulling Vgate to common, and a pull-up to 24V turns them (slowly) off again. However, P channels are often more expensive or have higher on resistance.

In my opinion the best option would be to use **High Side Switches**.
Such as an BTS4142, but you can get more advanced versions with diagnostics and sensing.

*A bonus feature of high side switches is that they are more robust than a standard fet or transistor since they include thermal shutdown and load dump protection.*

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your load. You should be able to use any transistor. Or an open collector buffer. You can drive the 74LS07 with a minimum high level voltage of 2 V, so 3.3 V should trigger it securely. And it can take up to 30 V into it's open-collector. Data sheet says I(OL) of 40 mA, not sure why they say "output low", that should be zero. So 40 mA at 30 V should be safe perhaps? After that a power transistor.

Your circuit seems to have Q1OUT1 tied to COM, i.e., always zero, and the FET shorted from VIN1 to COM when it opens. So as planned I'd say it (or something around it) will "boil to death" quickly.

And now I see you have an opto-cupler as input here, so it depends on its data sheet. That PC817 you show here can take 80 V over collector-emitter already. And 50 mA. So tie it via a pull-up (and current limiting) resistor to your 24 voltage without a problem.